# Redirect loop issue in Silex SecurityServiceProvider

Tags: php, security, authentication, silex

I've got a issue creating a login form to authenticate users. I followed exactly the example in this page: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#defining-more-than-one-firewall, but I've got a redirect loop when I try to access my site.

I'd like to secure my entire website, so I wrote this lines:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
        'security.firewalls' => array(
            'login' => array(
                'pattern' => '^/login$',
            ),
            'secured' => array(
                'pattern' => '^.*$',
                'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/login_check'),
                'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/logout'),
                'users' => array(
                    // password is foo
                    'user1' => array('ROLE_USER', '5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg=='),
                ),
            ),
        ),
));

$app->mount('/login', include '../src/login.php');
```

Then I created a `login.php` file:

```
$controllers->get('/', function(Silex\Application $app, Request $request) {
    return $app->render('login.html.twig', array(
        'error'         => $app['security.last_error']($request),
        'last_username' => $app['session']->get('_security.last_username'),
    ));
});
```

When I try to go to my homepage `http://localhost` I've got a redirect loop message by the browser.

Where am I wrong?

Thanks all!

Comment: Ok I spotted the issue: it's on the mount behaviour with `/login` path and inside the php file on `$controllers->get` with `/` parameter. I had to change those lines in: `$app->mount('/', include '../src/login.php');`

And in the `login.php`:

    `$controllers->get('/login', ...`

Comment: You should create this as answer of your question and mark it as resolution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I spotted the issue: it's on the mount behaviour with `/login` path. I had to change those lines in:

> $app->mount('/', include '../src/login.php');

And in the login.php:

> $controllers->get('/login', ...